# Remove whitespace from CSV row

Tags: ruby, csv, whitespace

I need to remove or stripe white space from CSV rows.

test.csv

```
60 500, # want 60500
8 100, # want 8100
5 400, # want 5400
480, # want 480
```

remove_space.rb

```
require 'csv'
CSV.foreach('test.csv') do |row|
    row = row[0]
    row = row.strip
    row = row.gsub(" ","")
    puts row
end
```

I don't understand why it doesn't work. Result is same as test.csv

Any idea?

Comment: `CSV` stands for _comma-separated values_. IMO your file is not in `CSV` format. What exactly is your expected output?

Comment: @spickermann I just update my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `test.csv` file contains [narrow no-break space](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/202f/index.htm) (U+202F) unicode characters. This is a *non-whitespace* character. (A regular space character is U+0020.)

You can see the different possible unicode spaces here: http://jkorpela.fi/chars/spaces.html

Here is a more generic script - using a [POSIX bracket group](https://www.regular-expressions.info/posixbrackets.html) - to remove all "space-like" characters:

```
require 'csv'
CSV.foreach('test.csv') do |row|
  row = row[0]
  row = row.gsub(/[[:space:]]/,"")
  puts row
end
```

Comment: thank you I didn't knwo! I will read different unicode spaces

Answer (score 2):

The thing is those are **not normal spaces** but rather [Narrow No-Break Spaces](https://unicode-table.com/en/202F/):

```
require 'csv'
CSV.foreach('/tmp/test.csv') do |row|
    puts row[0].delete "\u202f"
end
#⇒ 60500
#  8100
#  5400
#  480
```

You can strip out *all the spaces*, including unicode ones, by using [`\p{Space}` matcher](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Regexp.html#class-Regexp-label-Character+Properties).

```
require 'csv'
CSV.foreach('/tmp/test.csv') do |row|
    puts row[0].gsub /\p{Space}/, ''
end
```